# jQuery is not finding elements loaded with AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jqtouch

I have a page like this:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="jqtouch.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="myfunctions.js"></script>

    [...]

</head>

<body>
    [...]
    <div id="jqt">
    <div id="home" class="current">
        <div class="toolbar">
            TITLE
        </div>
        <div class="s-scrollwrapper">
            <div class="content">
                <div class="container" >
                    <a href="/thepage.php">LOAD ME 1</a><a href="/thepage.php">LOAD ME 2</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    [...]
</body>
```

The contents of the loaded page is like this, for example:

```
<div id="AG3456AF002347634">
<div class="toolbar">
TITLE 1
</div>
<div class="s-scrollwrapper">
    <div class="content">
        <div class="container" >
            <div style="display:none" id="myItemId"></div><button onclick="javascript: showItem();"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

showItem is a function located in myfunctions.js and the contents is, for example this:

```
function showItem() {jQuery(jQT.hist[0].hash + ' #myItemId').show();}
```

so when i click on the button, after the page is loaded, jQT.hist[0].hash value is #AG3456AFGG2347634. This works fine the first time that i load a page with AJAX (well, when jQTouch does it). But if i load another page with same content (but the main identifier is different) it doesn't work. After two AJAX calls, the page dom is simmilar to this:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="jqtouch.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="myfunctions.js"></script>

    [...]

</head>

<body>
    [...]
    <div id="jqt">
        <div id="home">
            <div class="toolbar">
                TITLE
            </div>
            <div class="s-scrollwrapper">
                <div class="content">
                    <div class="container" >
                        <a href="/thepage.php">LOAD ME 1</a><a href="/thepage.php">LOAD ME 2</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="AG3456AF002347634">
            <div class="toolbar">
                TITLE 1
            </div>
            <div class="s-scrollwrapper">
                <div class="content">
                    <div class="container" >
                        <div style="display:none" id="myItemId"></div><button onclick="javascript: showItem();"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="FC00A83473BE33457" class="current">
            <div class="toolbar">
                TITLE 2
            </div>
            <div class="s-scrollwrapper">
                <div class="content">
                    <div class="container" >
                        <div style="display:none" id="myItemId"></div><button onclick="javascript: showItem();"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
    [...]
</body>
```

so when i click the button on the second loaded page it doesn't works cause jQuery is not finding the item. the value of jQT.hist[0].hash is correct, that is #FC00A83473BE33457. The item id #myItemId is the same on both pages, that's the reason to use the wrapper div id that it's unique, to locate each loaded item.

Why this is working on the first page but it's not when i load additional pages into the DOM??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use the "live" command in jQuery for dynamic loaded content.. Pass a class to your button (like .myButton) and to your div container (.container) and use :

```
$('.myButton').live('click', function(){
    //and scope from $(this) here
    $(this).parents().find('.container:first').attr('id');
});
```

Comment: but i need to call the function located in myfunctions.js to avoid loading again and again the same javascript function. I'm not sure to understand your code... what do i put into the live function?

Comment: the problem is how can i locate the new loaded items using jQuery from my function located into myfunctions.js that it's loaded all the time.

Comment: If you put that function in document.ready it will be available across all scripts. That function says : for all instances of myButton class, when i click on it, find the parent div that has the container class. You can embed that function in your loaded class as well if you want to.

Comment: but my situation is a bit more complicated, previously i was passing a parameter to my function using the onclick located for each button. That parameter is needed because i use it in my function to call jQuery.post('page.php?param=' + functionParameter, function(data) { ... });

Comment: using your approach, with the live jQuery function, i can't pass any parameter to the function

Comment: then either call a function from that live function or add it here like : $('.myButton').live('click', function(){  var id = $(this).parents().find('.container:first').attr('id'); someFunction(id);

Comment: If you load some functions in another JS file, you still can access them. I think it's more of a design issue (MVC anyone?) that a code issue :)

Comment: Finally i've done some changes and the jQuery live function did the trick. It's working now... many thanks for your help Eric :)

Comment: @FidoBoy Can you explain how you made this work. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I suggest using the jQuery .on() method instead of live, it's a newer method (live has some problems), read about it: http://api.jquery.com/on/

As for passing parameters you can add an attribute to the element clicked or call your function from inside the .on() callback with the parameter, Or even do a little (ugly) hack and use .on for the 'load' (or 'ready') events instead of 'click' and add the onclick (if there is really no other way). Something like:

```
$(".myButton").on("load", function(event){
  $(this).attr('onclick' , yourFunction)
});
```

But you probably can make it work in a cleaner way with just .on().

Answer (score 0):

Ids are singular, you can not have more than one id with the same value on the page.

Change the ids to classes and reference it that way.

Comment: problem is not the ids, the problem is that jQuery is not seeing the new loaded elements, even if its id are unique (like <div id="AG3456AF002347634">). There is duplicated ids into the main div, but the first id is unique so, combining them should do the trick...

Comment: It does not matter, ids are SINGULAR. [HTML5 Spec](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Global_attributes#attr-id)